# User Permission

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml, vb.net

In my web application we have many users.I want to set permission for each user.In our windows application we used Database to store the Permission(Insert,Modify,delete and View).In web application can anybody tell me about where to store the permission.Somebody told that if we use database it will take so much time?In the case of XML it is easy and not taking much time.But if the client set permission for number of users,then it will create problem?....Please Give some idea

(Permission means in case of "Category" page which user can view the Category page,which user can edit information about category,which user can delete information of category,which user can add new category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave it to the asp.net experts (one of which i most definitely are not) to recommend when to use the Asp.net Membership that Shoban suggested. I would advise, however, not to store the information in a disk file. Especially one can be user altered. You are asking for concurrency issues (especially with xml). Storing things in a database is just fine for this application. Once the overhead of the connection to the database server is handled (which probably isn't a big deal anyway because of connection pooling and is probably required by your app anyway, no?) the retrieval of info from the database is not a performance drag. So, use a database to store this info - if that database can be managed by the Asp.net Membership features the more power to you. If you want/need to roll your own, that is just fine.
-don

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ASP.net Membersip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx). This can help you develop your framework of storing user credentials and creating different roles. You will then have to develop your application to allow/disallow certain operations based on user's role.